# SSRS - Error with SSAS datasource on certain users

Tags: reporting-services, ssas

I'm currently setting up the security on SSRS reports at the customer location.
A few of the SSRS reports have a MD cube as a datasource.
When I'm trying to execute a report with an certain user I get an error showed below:

```
processing!ReportServer_0-1!520!09/28/2018-12:10:30:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: Cannot create a connection to data source 'Cube'. ---> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnectionException: The connection either timed out or was lost. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.DimeRecord.ForceRead(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 length)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.DimeRecord.ReadHeader()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.DimeReader.ReadRecord()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.TcpStream.GetResponseDataType()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.EndRequest(Boolean useBinaryXml)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.SendMessage(Boolean endReceivalIfException, Boolean readSession, Boolean readNamespaceCompatibility)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.SupportsProperty(String propName)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.Connect(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Boolean beginSession)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.XmlaClientProvider.Connect(Boolean toIXMLA)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.ConnectToXMLA(Boolean createSession, Boolean isHTTP)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.AdomdExceptionHandler.Execute(String connectionString, Action action)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.AdoMdConnectionBase.Open()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.DataExtensionConnectionBase.<>c__DisplayClass5.<OpenConnection>b__4()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---;
processing!ReportServer_0-1!520!09/28/2018-12:10:30:: e ERROR: Data source 'Cube': An error has occurred. Details: Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: Cannot create a connection to data source 'Cube'. ---> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnectionException: The connection either timed out or was lost. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
processing!ReportServer_0-1!520!09/28/2018-12:10:30:: e ERROR: An exception has occurred in data source 'Cube'. Details: Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: Cannot create a connection to data source 'Cube'. ---> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnectionException: The connection either timed out or was lost. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
processing!ReportServer_0-1!520!09/28/2018-12:10:30:: i INFO: DataPrefetch abort handler called for Report with ID=. Aborting data sources ...
```

I have three AD user groups defined (admins, users and agents).
For the users in my "admins" and "users" these reports work fine.
For the "agents" users I get the error.

I have checked the roles on the SSAS MD cube and they all have the same security at this point.
Here are already a few things I've tried:

1. I have tried to delete the user in the "Membership" section and re-added him, without any luck.
2. Removed the SSRS reports (with the error) from the report server and re-added them, without any luck.
3. Restarted the SSRS service, without any luck
4. Executing the report with an "Admins" user, was successfull (no errors)
5. Executing the report with an "Users" user, was successfull (no errors)
6. Connected with an "Agents" user to the cube via Excel, was successfull
7. Tried executing the SSRS reports with serveral other "Agents" users, without any luck.

I'm out of ideas now, anyone else got some suggestions?
Note: I don't have access to there AD (this goes through another partner)

Thanks
Kevin

Comment: Can the agents run any reports or is it just this one? Is there anything in the report itself that does anything with the agent user group? Are the roles in SSRS set up differently within SSRS itself?

Comment: Agents can't run any reports based on the MD cube.
There is nothing in the report specific to an agent (at this moment the Users usergroup is exactly the same as Agents user group)
Normally the roles aren't different between SSAS and SSRS. In SSRS I control the visibility of reports for certain user groups.
The cube security is within the roles of SSAS.

Comment: What kind of authentication is set up in the data source? Is it windows auth? And I assume it's only one data source for all the reports to connect to the MD cube? Is the data source in the reports a shared data source?

Comment: Yes, the authentication is set to Windows Credentials. There is indeed only 1 datasource created on the MD cube. I have changed the shared datasource to a report specific datasource which connects to the cube but this gives me the same error. I have even tried to execute the MDX query in SSMS as one of those agents and I get data when I execute the query.